# Is there really a proper way to send private bits even 1 with CANBUS?

Tags: can, bus, protocol

I was thinking of making an authentication protocol for canbus. Is there a way to send even 1bit privately to another node ? Have seen many implementations quite a few good ones. In particular ESA Academy states that they have a way to send a private bit within nodes. Do you think its possible ?

Comment: Depends on what you mean with "private". At the higher protocol layers, certainly... that's not really related to CAN.

Comment: What do you mean by that

Comment: At the hardware level, there is no privacy - every node can see what is happening on the bus. To decouple what is happening on the bus from the actual bit you want to send/receive, you will need encryption, which requres a secret key shared between the sender and the receiver.

Comment: Agree on hardware level there is no privacy. As for secret key you mean that it will be defined ? Or how you think of that

Comment: Just study encryption, this has nothing to do with electronics.

Comment: @Lundin it has to do with CANBus

Comment: No, the payload can be anything and the CAN bus doesn't care.